# How to add dynamic height to a div along with its html code using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the code not working while attempting to add the html code along with programmatic height..

```
$("table").after("<div style=height: '"+getHeight+"'></div>");
```

The div gets added but without the programmatic height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting invalid html :

```
$("table").after('<div style="height:' + getHeight + 'px"></div>');
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wykfbs92/)